# Использование методов контроллера на двух страницах jsf

Tags: java, spring, jsf, primefaces

Есть контроллер:

**CompanyController.java**

```
@Controller("companyController")
public class CompanyController {

@Autowired
private CompanyService companyService;

private String name;

private int id;

public void saveCompany(){
    Company company = new Company();
    company.setName(name);
    companyService.save(company);
}

public void removeCompany(){
    companyService.remove(id);
}

public List<Company> findAll(){
    return companyService.findAll();
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/companies", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView companies(ModelAndView modelAndView){
    modelAndView.setViewName("companies");

    return modelAndView;
}


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

Стартовая страница:
**login.xhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough" xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">

<h:head>
<title>Main page</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
<f:view>

    <h:form>
        <p:panel>
            <p:commandButton action="#{mainController.showCompanies}" value="Show Companies"/>
            <p:commandButton action="#{mainController.showEmployees}" value="Show Employees"/>
        </p:panel>


        <h:outputLabel value="Companies:"/>

        <p:panel>
            <p:outputLabel for="nameInputText" value="Name"/>
            <p:inputText id="nameInputText" title="Enter name" value="#{companyController.name}"/>
            <p:commandButton action="#{companyController.saveCompany}" value="Save"/>
        </p:panel>

        <p:panel>
            <p:outputLabel for="idInputText" value="Id"/>
            <p:inputText id="idInputText" title="Enter ID" value="#{companyController.id}"/>
            <p:commandButton action="#{companyController.removeCompany}" value="Remove"/>
        </p:panel>


        <h:outputLabel value="Employees: "/>

        <p:panel>
            <p:outputLabel for="employeeNameInputText" value="Name"/>
            <p:inputText id="employeeNameInputText" title="Enter name" value="#{employeeController.name}"/>
            <p:outputLabel for="employeeAgeInputText" value="Age"/>
            <p:inputText id="employeeAgeInputText" title="Enter name" value="#{employeeController.age}"/>
            <p:outputLabel for="employeeSalaryInputText" value="Salary"/>
            <p:inputText id="employeeSalaryInputText" title="Enter name" value="#{employeeController.salary}"/>
            <p:outputLabel for="employeePositionInputText" value="Position"/>
            <p:inputText id="employeePositionInputText" title="Enter name" value="#{employeeController.position}"/>
            <p:outputLabel for="employeeCompanyIdInputText" value="Company Id"/>
            <p:inputText id="employeeCompanyIdInputText" title="Enter name" value="#{employeeController.companyId}"/>
            <p:commandButton action="#{employeeController.saveEmployee}" value="Save"/>
        </p:panel>

        <p:panel>
            <p:outputLabel for="employeeIdInputText" value="Id"/>
            <p:inputText id="employeeIdInputText" title="Enter ID" value="#{employeeController.id}"/>
            <p:commandButton action="#{employeeController.remove}" value="Remove"/>
        </p:panel>

    </h:form>
</f:view>
</h:body>

</html>
```

На данной страннице методы контроллера работают. Но если перейти на страницу **companies.xhtml** c точно такими же методами, то ничего не происходит. Ошибок в браузере никаких нет, до сервера просто ничего не доходит.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough" xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">

<h:head>
<title>Companies</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
<f:view>
    <p:panel>
        <p:outputLabel for="nameInputText" value="Name"/>
        <p:inputText id="nameInputText" title="Enter name" value="#{companyController.name}"/>
        <p:commandButton action="#{companyController.saveCompany}" value="Save"/>
    </p:panel>
    <p:panel>
        <p:outputLabel for="idInputText" value="Id"/>
        <p:inputText id="idInputText" title="Enter ID" value="#{companyController.id}"/>
        <p:commandButton action="#{companyController.removeCompany}" value="Remove" update="companyList"/>
    </p:panel>
    <p:panel id="companyList">
        <h:dataTable value="#{companyController.findAll()}" var="company">
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Id"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{company.id}"/>
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Name"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{company.name}"/>
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
    </p:panel>

</f:view>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А дело оказалось в обычной невнимательности..(

Не добавил теги **h:form**.

После этого кнопки начали работать.
Кстати, у кого будут схожие проблемы, вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandbutton-commandlink-ajax-action-listener-method-not-invoked-or-input-value/2120183#2120183) много решений таких проблем с jsf.